# Status Report vs Available Updates

Tags: status-messages

My Status report shows that my Drupal version is 7.32 but my Available Updates page says 7.30. Can you tell me why they would be different? No recent updates have been made.

Comment: When does the "Last Checked" say it ran?  The info in your question is a little odd, as 7.34 is the latest version.  And, please clarify if you are *positive* you upgraded to 7.32 yourself b/c SA-CORE-2014-005.

Comment: Last Checked on Available Updates says 0 seconds. I didn't clarify. No, I didn't upgrade to 7.32. The site launched back in October by another developer. The developer told me that it was at the latest version when launched which would be 7.32. However, the website owner mentioned that they have been getting a lot of attempts at logins which led me to look at the admin area yesterday. I looked at available updates and saw 7.30. I thought I looked at Status Report as well and it was 7.30 but when I went in this morning and saw 7.32 in status report, am doubting myself. Could there be a reason?

Answer (score 0):

This could indicate that your site was hacked due to drupalgeddon bug. If you have not updated from 7.30 it is likely that an attacker changed the version numbers. Check here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2357241

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I was told by another developer that it had been updated back in October to 7.32 but I am concerned this is not the case and I just want to ensure there would be no other reason for there to be difference between these two pages (Status Report and Available Updates).

Comment: You surely should thoroughly check with the other developer if he did the update. If you are not sure, then there is a high risk that the site is compromised and the best bet would be to restore from backup before October 15 2014 if possible.